# Why doesn't friction cause imbalanced forces like weight or $F_{\rm applied}$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I went over forces in my Physics C class months ago, and when I asked this question in class and got an answer, it made sense. However, looking back I'm not satisfied his response.

[image: In this photo the Fapp causes the box to move to the right since it is larger than Ffrict. I get that.]

In this diagram the Fapp causes the box to move to the right since it is larger than Ffrict. I get that.

What happens when Ffrict and Fapp switch? Like if Ffrict were greater than Fapp if say the weight of the object increased, making normal larger, and therefore Ffriction. Why doesn't the box start being "pulled by friction".

[image]

I understand that nothing gets moved by friction, but why does the "imbalanced forces cause acceleration" apply to friction?

Edit: added 2nd photo.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to keep in mind is that just because an object has an acceleration in one direction does not mean it is moving in that direction.

Friction always acts in the opposite direction of displacement (assuming kinetic, not static friction), therefore in the case when the magnitude of friction is larger than the applied force, it must be that the object is still moving in the direction of the applied force. It will just have a decreasing speed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I would up vote it, but I need 15 reputation. This makes sense. Especially the part about how it must be moving in order to have a larger force.

Comment: You can still select a main answer though right?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of friction:  
*Kinetic friction*: The friction when something moves and is **constant**. Like the first picture you mentioned.

*Static friction:* The friction when something doesn't move and **changes**. 
Take a look at this image:
[image: friction]
As the force(x-axis) applied on a object increase, the friction(y-axis) is linearly increasing and equals the force Hence the object is in equilibrium.
When the force applied increases above a certain point the friction is no longer linear and is not able to oppose the force completely hence it moves forward.

Comment: Thank you very much, that visual was helpful as well. Wish I could upvote but I need 15 reputation.

Comment: Where is "this image"?  Without it your answer doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Switching the direction of the arrows does not make one greater than the other.  You need to consider how friction arises in a given situation.

There is static friction and kinetic friction.  Nether of these will ever be grater than the force applied.  If the applied horizontal force is zero there is no friction acting on the object.  Friction can be thought of as tiny contact forces between rough patches on both surfaces, ridges and valleys at a micron size scale.  If no one is pushing or pulling the object across the surface these contact forces are not activated in the horizontal direction.  As you increase the applied force there is static friction which will "balance" the applied force until static friction is broken, at a value of mu_s * |N|, where N is the normal force.  After that the friction is kinetic and always equal to mu_k * |N| regardless of the size of the applied force in the horizontal direction.  If that applied force gets too small the object will stop and static friction will activate again.  There simply is no way for the friction force to be greater than the applied force.